# How to automatically remove entries after a certain time?

Tags: entries, tasks, cron, delete

I haven't found anything similar to this. But I was wondering if it's possible to delete certain entries after a certain time?

For example: User fills in form and adds contact entry - after 2 weeks this entry gets removed automatically. This way the database won't fill up, and the overview will stay clean.

I was thinking a cronjob every 24h that checks the postdate and when the postdate is over 2 weeks it gets removed. However I'm not sure if this is possible with craft cms?

Answer (score 2):

To only disable an entry, use this:[image]

If entries need to be deleted, you can create a custom plugin, where entries will be deleted when expired or when the postdate is older than 2 weeks..

Comment: It has to actually be deleted, so a custom plugin will probably be the solution. Thank you very much!